# '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10}Extension' is unexpect

Tags: uwp, desktop-bridge, visual-studio-2017

I want to run Win32 process from my UWP Desktop application.

When I add this to Package.appxmanfest:

```
<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="AudioConversion/AudioConversion.exe">
  <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
    <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="SyncGroup" Parameters="/Sync"/>
    <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="OtherGroup" Parameters="/Other"/>
  </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
</desktop:Extension>
```

I get following error:

> Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The
>   app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 52, Column 6, Reason:
>   Element
>   '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10}Extension'
>   is unexpect

Comment: It seems the error was fixed in VS2017 (v15.1). Source: [Validation error. error C00CE014 App manifest validation error](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/42962/validation-error-error-c00ce014-app-manifest-valid.html)

Comment: No, I'm still getting the error in latest VS2017.2 (updated few hours ago)

Comment: Then Report this problem. They might help

Comment: Meanwhile, solution seems to add desktop to IgnorableNamespaces in the root element, although it is not mentioned in the documentation